# Stripping letter suffix from product identifiers?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a CSV file with a list of SKU's, each of which is a separate row corresponding to other product attributes like description, color, etc.

I need to import product color swatches for identical item identifiers that have multiple colors. I need to find a common identifier to make as a base for the rest of the colors.

So the data is like:

[image]

I need to cut the letter(s) suffix and paste it to the adjacent column, leaving just the base identifier from which I can remove duplicates and filter the base. The hard part is that each identifier can have different suffix length, so the next item can be **ACC3205A-SET2** -- the only real consistency is that every item has three *prefix* letters (**ABC)** followed by four adjacent numbers. Everything after that should be removed and pasted to adjacent column. Is this easily doable in VBA?

Comment: This can be done with a formula, if you need to just split out everything after the 7th letter.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized they can have slightly differing lengths, but the part to remove always starts with a letter.

Comment: Please [edit] your question then to reflect that, thanks!

Comment: I just realized the premise of the question is off, maybe it's better to repost it? I didn't quite understand the use case but now do :/

Comment: I don't see any problem with [edit]ing it but up to you.

Comment: OK, I'll just edit, thanks!

Comment: If it is always 7 leading characters: base formula is: =LEFT(A1,7) and the remainder is: =RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-7)